# Decomposing an absolute value function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(z) = |x^2 - y^2| + 2i|xy|$.

I'm having trouble decomposing this function so that we can get rid of the absolute value signs. I think I should break it up into multiple regions, $x^2 + y^2 > 0$, $x^2 + y^2 <0$, $x,y > 0$, $x,y < 0$, $x > 0, y< 0$...

but this doesn't seem right. Can anyone help?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 < 0\ $?

Comment: sorry, I meant -x^2 + y^2 < 0

Comment: you need to correct your question then.

Comment: Hm, I think I misunderstand what your confusion is. I'll await an answer as the question I have currently written is correct.

Comment: No it's not, you still have $x^2+y^2< 0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^{2}-y^{2}=(x+y)(x-y)$.  That is, we can realize both $x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $xy$ as products.  Naturally, the pair are positive whenever both factors of each have the same sign: $x^{2}-y^{2}>0$ when $x+y>0$ and $x-y>0$ or when $x+y<0$ and $x-y<0$, and $xy>0$ whenever both $x$ and $y$ are positive or when both are negative.  Analagously, the expressions $x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $xy$ are negative whenever $x+y$ and $x-y$ have opposite sign and whenever $x$ and $y$ have opposite sign.

Let's consider $|x^{2}-y^{2}|$ in isolation.

The region where $x^{2}-y^{2}$ is positive is the union of the following two sets:

$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|y>-x\}\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|x>y\}$$ 
$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|y<-x\}\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|y>x\}$$

The first set is the intersection of the half-plane in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ above the line $y=-x$ with the half-plane in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ below the line $y=x$.  Draw this.  The second set is the intersection of the half-plane below the line $y=-x$ with the half-plane above the line $y=x$.  Draw this.  Once you have drawn the two shaded regions, you know that these two regions together make the total space in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ over which $x^{2}-y^{2}$ is positive.

Do analagous drawings for the other cases, and this should help you put together a piece-wise definition for your function f.